# How do I use results from iOS EKCalendarChooser to change to selected calendar?

Tags: ios, ekeventkit, ekevent

I have setup EKCalendarChooser to allow user to pick a Calendar and I have setup EKCalendarChooserDelegate Protocol to check on selection. I do get a calendarChooserDidFinish
with the results but I still not clear how to change over to calendar. I see the selectedCalendars property but I guess I was expecting a way to set the the pick Calendar by setting eventStore or identifier - I may be having using using NSSet that is coming back?

So when I change a Calendar I have done something along the lines of

```
  self.defaultCalendar = [self.eventStore calendarWithIdentifier:identifier];
```

or id creating a new Calendar

```
    self.defaultCalendar = [EKCalendar calendarWithEventStore:eventStore];
    self.defaultCalendar.title = @"Demo calendar";
    self.defaultCalendar.source = localSource;
    [eventStore saveCalendar:self.defaultCalendar commit:YES error:nil];
```

How do I change to new select Calendar from EKCalendarChooser ?

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your problem correctly, then your looking for how to set your calendar when you receive `calendarChooser.selectedCalendars` property in your delegate method?

Provided you only allow one calendar to be set in your `EKCalendarChooser` then you can do something along the lines of:

```
- (void)calendarChooserSelectionDidChange:(EKCalendarChooser *)calendarChooser
{
    EKCalendar *newCalendar = [calendarChooser.selectedCalendars anyObject];
}
```

If you allow more than one calendar to be selected then you'll need to loop through the NSSet instead.

Comment: Could you include an answer with the multiple selection feature? I'd greatly appreciate it